# Should the 'download' query string parameter work in the HTML5 SoundCloud player?

Tags: api, download, soundcloud

I was looking at the Soundlcoud Widget docs
http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/widget#

I noticed there is a parameter for 'download'. I tried it on the HTML5 sharing widget it didn't turn on the download link. Is there a way to show the Download link?

Example
http://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F46911134&auto_play=false&show_artwork=true&color=ff7700&download=true&sharing=false

Thanks

Comment: I think I figured it out. If I set 'buying' to false, then the download button shows up. Seems they both can't co-exists. 

http://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F46911134&auto_play=false&show_artwork=true&color=ff7700&download=true&sharing=false&buying=false

Comment: that seems like a bug in player then. I'll lodge a ticket and hopefully get this fixed for you soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually the intended behaviour. A lot of the time, the widget is displayed in a relatively small frame, and showing all the buttons creates too much visual clutter. A redesign (to use icons, for example) is coming, but I can't give you a date on when that will be ready. In the meantime, the documentation will be updated.

Comment: Appreciate the response and help with this.